# How to select the python interpreter for IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2022 preview?

Tags: python, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

How do I select which Python environment my IntelliSense should work with? The code uses the correct venv but the IntelliSense uses the Python that is specified in the Windows path.

- Running on Windows 10
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview (64-bit)
- Version 17.0.0 Preview 4.1
- Visual Studio IntelliCode 2.2
- Python with Pylance   17.0.21243.2
- etc.